# Can you disable sharing of datasets in bigquery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am wanting to disable the "Share dataset" feature of bigquery.

[image: disable]

For my use case I would like to disable this feature as you can't control what data can be shared and and who with. This means datasets are shareable with anyone who has gmail account.

I've been experimenting with removing various IAM permissions and I can't seem to pin it down. I've also used chrome dev tools to see what the API call is but I can't trace it back to how I can prevent the sharing of datasets.

If this cannot be disabled can you at least lock it down to a specific domain?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following steps to restrict the share option.

1. Add the user to the IAM and don't assign any role.
2. Share the dataset with the user with **Can view** role

Now the user can still see the Share dataset option, but if they try to share they will get the following error[image]

Answer (score 0):

As per [BigQuery permissions and roles matrix](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control) only Admin, Data owner(BigQuery role), and the Owner of a dataset can share it. Make sure to give the [least privilege](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/using-iam-securely) needed to your users.

For example, give the respective user the bigquery.jobUser permission and share him the dataset with "can edit" permission. This setup will not allow the dataset to be shared.